# How to pass a value to a global variable in apex

Tags: visualforce, map, list, pagereference, global-variables

```
public PageReference BookerInformation(){

        PageReference gotosetup = new PageReference('/apex/bookerinformation?id=' + eventId);

        List<ProntoEvents_Product__c> products_1 = [SELECT Id, Name FROM ProntoEvents_Product__c Where Event_Name__c = :eventId];
        Map<Id, String> prod_quantity = new Map<Id, String>();  
        for (ProntoEvents_Product__c data_prod : products_1){
            prod_quantity.put(data_prod.ID, ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get(data_prod.ID));

        }

        system.Debug(prod_quantity);
        gotosetup.setRedirect(true);
        return gotosetup;
    }
```

How can I pass this `prod_quantity` to a global variable so that I can use it on the visualforce page?

Sample output of the `prod_quantity` in `system.Debug` is this:

```
16:54:11.341 (341390959)|USER_DEBUG|[50]|DEBUG|{a0T9000000JplalEAB=15, a0T9000000Jple3EAB=0, a0T9000000JplfLEAR=5}
```

Comment: if your application can be more like a wizard, then by not using `setRedirect(true)`, the controller variables stay in memory for both pages. Otherwise, KeithC has the right answer

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are trying to make `prod_quantity` available to the next page, the `bookerinformation` page.

There is nowhere (except the database) at the moment in Salesforce to keep a value created in one page and make it available to another page. So the normal solution to your problem is to pass the value in the URL of the new page just as the `eventId` is being passed in the URL.

Providing your data is not too large (doesn't make the URL more than say 1k in length) you can encode and decode it into the URL like this:

```
public PageReference BookerInformation() {

    ...

    Map<Id, String> prod_quantity = ...;
    String encoded = EncodingUtil.urlEncode(JSON.serialize(prod_quantity), 'UTF-8')

    PageReference pr = new PageReference('/apex/bookerinformation');
    pr.getParamaters().put('id', eventId);
    pr.getParamaters().put('prod_quantity', encoded);
    pr.setRedirect(true);
    return pr;
}
```

and the new page can get the value like this:

```
String encoded = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('prod_quantity');
String decoded = EncodingUtil.urlDecode(encoded, 'UTF-8');
Map<Id, String> prod_quantity
        = (Map<Id, String>) JSON.deserialize(decoded, Map<Id, String>.class);
```

But generally it is better to find a way to pass a small identifier that the receiving page can use to query the data it needs.

Comment: If he's using the same controller for both pages, would .setRedirect(false) keep the variable for use in the next page?

Comment: @AntonioManente Yes if `prod_quantity` was also made a (non-static and non-transient) field of the class rather than a local variable that will not be preserved in the view state.